# Solving "string reduction" challenge

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have seen various discussions and code attempts at solving the ["String reduction"](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4eac48496bee2) problem from interviewstreet.com, but none of them does it via dynamic programming.

Listed under the [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) section, the problem is described as follows:

> Given a string consisting of a,b and c's, we can perform the following operation: Take any two adjacent distinct characters and replace it with the third character. For example, if 'a' and 'c' are adjacent, they can replaced with 'b'.
>
> What is the smallest string which can result by applying this operation **repeatedly**?

The problem can be solved using exhaustive brute-force search, effectively creating a tree of all possible substitutions:

```
// this is more or less pseudo code from my head
int GetMinLength(string s)
{
    // solve edge cases
    if (s.Length == 1) return 1;
    if (s.Length == 2) return ReduceIfPossible(s);

    // recursive brute force
    int min = s.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i<s.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != s[i+1])
        {
            var next = GetMinLength(
                  s.Substring(0, i) + 
                  Reduce(s[i], s[i + 1]) +
                  s.Substring(i + 2)
                  );

            if (next < min) min = next;
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously fails for larger `N` (`N <= 100`), so I am trying to break it into smaller subproblems, memoize them, and merge results.

The problem is that I cannot determine the state which would have ["optimal substructure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure), needed to apply dynamic programming (or in other words to "merge" results from sub-problems). Minimizing a part of the string doesn't guarantee that the final string will really be the smallest solution.

What would be the subproblem "state" in this case, which could be merged towards the final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes this tricky is that you need to treat this as 2 dynamic programming problems in a row.

1. Build up a table of, by character you wind up with, by start position, all of the possible end positions that are a block that can be reduced to that character.
2. The smallest length that the final `i` characters of the string can be reduced to.  (The table that you built in step 1 can be used to recursively reduce this problem to already solved subproblems.)

The second provides your answer.  It is much more straightforward if you have already solved the first.

Comment: @Dilbert Exactly.  But make it a nested lookup - you can lookup by one thing then the other.  (This table is easiest to generate by starting at the end of the string then working backwards.)

Comment: Could you please clarify the first step a bit more? I think you want me to build a table of all blocks of length less than or equal to the problem string that can reduce to one of the three characters. But what do you mean by - 'by character you wind up with, by start position, '? I am a noob at DP.

Comment: @gautam1168 I meant exactly what I said. :-)  Given a final character and a start position, you need a list of all endpoints of ranges where you can collapse from that start position to that endpoint and wind up with that character.  This requires solving a DP problem for each startpoint that can be solved if you've solved the same problem for all later ones already.  (Note, you will have to do a lot of merging of ranges.  Look up "priority queues" for something that will help.)

Answer (score 1):

**Spoiler Alert code:**

```
public static int findMinReduction(String line){
    //Pseudocode:
    //Count the number of occurences of each letter in the input string.
    //If two of these counts are 0, then return string.length
    //Else if (all counts are even) or (all counts are odd), then return 2
    //Else, then return 1

    int len = line.length();
    String a_reduce = line.replaceAll("c", "").replaceAll("b", "");
    String b_reduce = line.replaceAll("a", "").replaceAll("c", "");
    String c_reduce = line.replaceAll("a", "").replaceAll("b", "");

    int a_occurances = a_reduce.length();
    int b_occurances = b_reduce.length();
    int c_occurances = c_reduce.length();

    if ((a_occurances == b_occurances && a_occurances == 0) || 
       (a_occurances == c_occurances && a_occurances == 0) || 
       (b_occurances == c_occurances && b_occurances == 0)){
        return len;
    }
    else{
        if (a_occurances % 2 == 0 && 
            b_occurances % 2 == 0 && 
            c_occurances % 2 == 0){
            return 2;
        }
        if (a_occurances % 2 != 0 
            && b_occurances % 2 != 0 && 
            c_occurances % 2 != 0){
            return 2;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**Complexity:**

This is an O(n) time complexity operation, as the input size increases, the amount of work to be done is linear with the size of the input.  Which is lightning quick, we can process for megabyte sized strings and still process them in fractions of a second.

**Algorithm found here with full analysis of why this algorithm works:**

[stumped on a Java interview, need some hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033553/stumped-on-a-java-interview-need-some-hints)

Comment: The [@Alderath's answer you linked to runs in linear time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8715230/1488067), not polynomial, and it's the same pseudocode from your comments. And it's not "almost zero time", it's plain and simple `O(n)`. So, comparing to his answer, and the answer by [@Matteo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8034276/1488067), you simply wrote the program in Java. Again, not sure what you meant by "Java8", though, as if you are using anything from version 8.

Comment: Fixed that it's generic java and answer has no java8 specific constructs.

Answer (score 0):

YOu start by creating a structure that describes a solution theory. It includes the number of characters considered, and the encoded string so far, and a worst case and best case for the theory.

At the beginning there is just one theory - no characters processed. Best case is a length 1 string ( e.g. a rule always applies and the string can be reduced to one character, and worst case is N, where no rules apply ) E.g.

```
encoded string = "";
encoded index = 0;
worst case = N; 
best case = 1;
```

Now start incrementing index by one, and adding a character to the encoded string. If no rules apply you keep that theory untouched. If a rule does apply you have a decision to make - either apply the rule or don't. So when you add a character you duplicate the theory for each rule that could apply to the last character, and keep one version for no rule applied. And you update best case and worst case for each theory.

At first the number of theories will multiply very quickly. But eventually you come to a situation where the worst case for some theories is better than the best case for other theories.

So any time you advance the index, you delete theories where the best case is worse than the theory with the best worst case. As index approaches N, most of the theories will drop out.